# How does jsFiddle allow and execute user-defined JavaScript without being dangerous?

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, eval, user-input

I've been working on a JS library and would like to setup a demo page on Github that allows, for example, users to define their own callbacks and execute commands.

I know "`eval()` is evil" and I can see how blind `eval()` of scripts could lead to XSS and other security issues. I'm trying to cook up some alternative schemes.

I really enjoy the interactivity of jsFiddle. I've taken a look at their source but was hoping someone could lay out here how jsFiddle allows and executes user-defined JavaScript without being dangerous. So long as it doesn't involve a 3rd party echo server, I'm hoping I can emulate the approach.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

jsFiddle executes user scripts on a separate domain, `http://fiddle.jshell.net` ([try it and see](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/rAXbE/)).
Therefore, it can't interact with the parent frame and it can't steal cookies.

You can actually do this without a separate server by placing a static page in a separate domain that reads from its querystring in Javascript.
You can communicate back using the page title (and so can the enemy).

Comment: What does it mean to execute on a separate domain -- load an iFrame containing a page that executes the JavaScript?

Comment: @editor: Exactly.  The page in the `<iframe>` must be on a separate domain that has nothing that can be attacked (no cookies)

Comment: @SLaks - Why does `alert(document.cookie);` works in jsFiddle?

Comment: a bit late. @ShlomiHassid the security concerns revolve around access to cookies, NOT access to your browser environment. hence, `alert('hello')` works and outputs "hello" in an alert box, but `alert(document.cookie)` only outputs an empty string (the alert box does still show up, but doesn't show any cookies unless the jshell.net domain has cookies on it)