# Inject Javascript from a textarea into an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, code-injection

I was trying to make a Code Playground like [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/).

It basicaly takes the CSS / HTML / Javascript Code out of different Textareas and injects it into an Iframe. It also should instantly update the Iframe.

However I'm a little bit stuck with injecting the Javascript.

---

***See, what I have done thus far:***

```
(function() {
    $('.grid').height( $(window).height() );    

    var contents = $('iframe').contents(),
        body = contents.find('body'),
        styleTag = $('<style></style>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));

    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.attr('id') === 'html') {
            body.html( $this.val() );
        } 
        if ( $this.attr('id') === 'css') {
            styleTag.text( $this.val() );
        }
    });

})();
```

This does inject the CSS and HTML, but not the Javascript.

I tried adding

```
        scriptTag = $('<script></script>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));
```

and

```
        if ( $this.attr('id') === 'javascript') {
            scriptTag.text( $this.val() );
        }
```

But it didn't work

---

***Somebody can help me out?***

Comment: Unrelated, but you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004001/how-does-jsfiddle-allow-and-execute-user-defined-javascript-without-being-danger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to inject the script tag and content at the same time, because inserting the `<script>` tag will cause the broswer to run the script. if the script content is inserted later, it may not be run, but I am not sure. try it like this:

```
$('<script></script>')
      .text($('theinputselectorhere').val())
      .appendTo(contents.find('head'));
```

Comment: you have to properly set the right context. alternatively, you can use the selector directly.

Comment: how to properly set the context?