# Inject Javascript from a textarea into an Iframe 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have made a playground

It takes HTML/CSS/JS from textareas and injects them into an Iframe. I had a problem in inserting JS.

I went to this site [Inject Javascript from a textarea into an Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964910/inject-javascript-from-a-textarea-into-an-iframe) (my code is exactly the same from net tuts+) but I wasn't able to understand

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
$('.grid').height( $(window).height() );    
var contents = $('iframe').contents(),
    body = contents.find('body'),
    styleTag = $('<style></style>').appendTo(contents.find('head')),
    scriptTag = $('<script></script>').text($('.js').val()).appendTo(contents.find('head'));
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.attr('id') === 'html') {
        body.html( $this.val() );
    } 
    if ( $this.attr('id') === 'css') {
        styleTag.text( $this.val() );
    }
});
})();
```

***Can someone help me***

Comment: Is the keyup event fired? I meant, do you call this snippet once elements are available in the DOM?

Comment: The html and css work on keyup so it should be working

Comment: Is `$('.js').val()` returning expected result? Anyway, you'd have better to provide online sample which replicates your issue

Comment: I have uploaded it online to [link](http://palash.comeze.com/)

Comment: I tried using `$('#js').val()` it still didn't work

Comment: I tested your link on chrome, seems to work as expected, the js is evaluated

Comment: Could you tell me the code you used

Comment: `<div>ok</div><script>alert(1)</script>`  Oops sory, i was setting it in HTML tab, i'm trying js tab now

Comment: Ya but the code wasn't in the js textarea

Comment: You would need to scroll down in the sidebar

Comment: You could suggest any other way to inject javascript if it there is any

Comment: As long as it works on the html elements

Comment: I'm currently trying to understand your issue, i mean debug it. It looks like you should handle exception will typing and use `styleTag.html( $this.val() );`

Comment: sorry for the long delay... So checking, it appears you need to reappend script tag to reevaluate its content on each keyup. I finally came to this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cowg850e/3/

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? The jsFiddle seems to work as expected

Comment: All changes are being done to the html page, Not the iframe.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: I'm not sure but I only want it to work on my iframe

Comment: For example I want it to click a button in the iframe. The button onclick function doesn't work

Comment: could you suggest me any method without keyup that will only work in an iframe and supports all the elements created in iframe #document