# Execute JavaScript code stored as a string with variable scopes

Tags: javascript, function, eval

## The problem

I'm creating a program that runs some user scripts in a confined and safe environment.
Since the users are able to share projects from one to another it could be really dangerous to do  `let fn = new Function(userScript);`  to load a script because, as the majority of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string) say, it could be used to run malicious scripts or modify the page's content by accessing global variables like `document` or `window`.

So I was thinking if it was possible to do something like this:

```
class MathHandler { ... } // Contains 'mathStuff' method

let globalVariable = "global!";

function init()
{
  let localVariable = "local!"

  let script = new Function('handler', '
    // This script shoudn't be able to access any variables (global or local)

    console.log(globalVariable); // Should give error
    console.log(localVariable); // Should also error

    document.getElementById("MyCanvas") // Same as before

    let foo = "bar";

    console.log(foo); // Should work fine

    handler.mathStuff("pow", 23); // This script should also be able to access given arguments
  ';
  
  func(MathHandler); //invoke the function using arguments

  eval(script, MathHandler);
}

init();
```

I also [created a simple scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh26r.png) to illustrate better the situation.

**TL;DR**: I'm trying to execute a string as a code without making it able to access local or global variables/methods.

## What I tried to do

I tried searching around the web for some answers but I couldn't find anything, probably because of some problems I had finding the correct 'terms' to describe the situation.

The closest answer to what I'm trying to achieve was a post talking about simulating a *whole* virtual machine that runs JavaScript, in Javascript, which I think it's a bit too much for this case. I also thought about using another language (like how Unity uses interacts with c# codes via c++) but I didn't think it was a good idea.

Comment: also [Safely sandbox and execute user submitted JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513212/safely-sandbox-and-execute-user-submitted-javascript) and [How to run user-provided Javascript without security issues (like jsFiddle, jsBin, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601865/how-to-run-user-provided-javascript-without-security-issues-like-jsfiddle-jsbi) and [Is it possible to sandbox JavaScript running in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser)

Comment: I didn't even think about using web workers because I thought they were unsafe but with a whitelist, it should work perfectly! Thanks so much for your response and all the useful links!

Comment: You might be looking for https://github.com/endojs/endo/blob/master/packages/ses/README.md